# Advance Search Webpart in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, search

Advance search webpart not visible in SharePoint2013. Any one suggest what to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the Advanced Search page in the search center site.  Edit the page and Export the Advanced Search Web Part.  After saving the exported web part file to your computer, go to the Web Part Gallery in the top level Site settings.  Click "Files" in the ribbon tabs and upload the file you just downloaded.

At that point, the Advanced Search Web Part should show up under the "Miscellaneous" group when inserting a web part a Team Site page.  If you edit the properties of the Advanced Search Web Part file in the Web Part Gallery to have a group of "Search" then it will show up under the Search group.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/99e6d5f2-76da-4fdd-8464-24159f12cee1/advanced-search-box-web-part-is-missing

Comment: no worries. I am glad it solve your issue

Comment: i have another issue.It would be great if you please look into it. i posted it with heading "Search document from document library on basis of current login user"

Comment: +1  - though it's shocking that this isn't already provided and we have to DIY in a service we are paying for.  The styling of the adv search box is also shockingly bad!